# What is the significance of IPv4 Link MTU?

Tags: 5g

Can someone please explain the significance of "IPv4 Link MTU" for Network to MS direction as well as for MS to network direction? What does SMF do when it receives "IPv4 Link MTU Request" in EPCO as part of the PDU session establishment request?